# Is it possible to release an App for iPad only in cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

We've created an iPad-App in Cordova(Phonegap) and the client want us to put it in the Appstore. Everything was setup but when we clicked on the Submit-Button in iTunes Connect, we get asked to upload Screenshots for iPhone too. But the App should be iPad only.
Where can i define that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In itunesconnect under screenshot section you need to select iPad as shown in image. and in Xcode project deployment info set device to iPad[image]

Comment: The problem with xcode when working on cordova is that the settings get overwritten. 

So your snipped:
<preference name= "target-device" value="iPad"/>

did not work, the terminal outputted the error that it couldn't understand the value iPad. 

what we did and what at the end worked for us was:
<preference name= "target-device" value="tablet"/>

but thank you for your help anyways! Your answer directed me to that solution, so here you go with the checkmark!

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode, you can go to your project settings and change the device target from Deployement Info, which is under General tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys! Is it possible to define this config somewhere in the config.xml? Because i noticed when we run our make-release script, everything from xcode gets overwritten by cordova

Comment: hope this helps you : <preference name= "target-device"  value="iPad"/>

Comment: @Sujania that is the almost correct answer in fact, Cordova introduced it in late 2014. `<preference name= "target-device" value="tablet"/>` Possible values are: handset, tablet, or universal